# Instance-private, typed context in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a sort of scraper or data miner in Haskell. It consists of a main loop and other shared logic, along with a number of "adapters" each of which is designed to scrape a particular type of resource (not only web pages but possibly filesystem objects as well). The adapters all produce the same type of result but I would like them to be independent otherwise. Also, I would like them to share the main loop and other logic.

This is what I have so far, using ExistentialQuantification to hide the adapter affiliation of a scraping job. My idea is that the main loop processes a sequence of jobs, dispatching on the "process" method to find the right adapter implementation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

-- Metadata about an article
data Article = Article
    { articleSource :: Text
    , articleTitle :: Text
    , articleUrl :: Text
    , articleText :: Text
    , articleDate :: Maybe Text
    }
    deriving (Show)

-- Adapter for scraping a certain type of resource.
--
-- The adapter provides a seed job constructor which samples the current config
-- and creates a seed job to be run first. The seed job then generates all
-- other jobs, e.g. by scraping an index page.
--
--- Each adapter module exports a value of this type, and nothing else.
data Adapter = Adapter
    { adapterName :: Text
    , adapterSeedJob :: ScraperConfig -> AnyJob
    }

-- Each scrape operation produces zero or more articles, and zero or more
-- new scrape jobs.
type ScrapeResult j = ExceptT AdapterErr IO ([Article], [j])

-- Specification of a resource to be scraped by a certain adapter.
--
-- Each adapter defines its own job type, containing the necessary information.
class ScrapeJob j where
    jobAdapter :: j -> Text
    jobDesc :: j -> Text
    jobProcess :: j -> ScrapeResult j

-- Opaque type encapsulating any adapter's job type, used outside the adapter.
data AnyJob = forall j. ScrapeJob j => AnyJob j

instance ScrapeJob AnyJob where
    jobAdapter (AnyJob j) = jobAdapter j
    jobDesc (AnyJob j) = jobDesc j
    jobProcess (AnyJob j) = wrap <$> jobProcess j
        where wrap (as, js) = (as, AnyJob <$> js)

-- Global configuration, such as which passwords to use
data ScraperConfig = ScraperConfig
    { -- ...
    }
```

My problem is that each adapter also has some context attached to it. One example would be that most adapters need to perform some kind of login procedure before it can access any data. I would like this to be handled separately from the scraping itself if possible, but I can't use the trick with AnyJob for "AnyContext" (I think) since there would be no way for the main loop of guaranteeing that the types of the AnyJob and AnyContext match up correctly.

My current ideas, neither of which I'm really satisfied with, are:

1. Fix the type of the context to a "bag of data" such as Map Text Text and add a special setup method to each adpater which creates this context.
2. Add the required context as a field of every ScrapeJob instance, and copy it along explicitly whenever a new job is created.
3. Turn the design upside down, letting each adapter run its own main loop using shared functions defined in a utility module.

Is there something I'm missing here? Any advice on how to improve on this design would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this a `class` at all as opposed to, say, `data ScrapeJob = ScrapeJob { adapter :: Text, desc :: Text, process :: ExceptT AdapterError IO ([Article], [ScrapeJob]) }`? If you use a `data` instead of a `class`, then you can simply close over whatever additional data is necessary, e.g. `filesystemJob :: FilePath -> ScrapeJob`, `webJob :: Password -> ScrapeJob`, etc.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks, that does seem simpler! I will try it out.

Comment: Also, ScrapeJob feels very much like a function with a signature looking something like this `ScrapeJob :: Text -> Text -> j -> ScrapeResult j`

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend sticking with existential polymorphism here—a plain record is simpler—but for future reference, you can express “these types are the same, but opaque from the outside” with an existential: `data Do a = Do (a -> Int); data With a = With a; data DoWith = forall a. DW (Do a) (With a)`. When you pattern-match on this, you get a proof in scope that the `a`s are the same, so you can use them together, with no knowledge of the concrete type: if `run :: DoWith -> Int; run (DW (Do f) (With x)) = f x`, then `run (DW (Do length) (With "hello")) == 5`.